# pandas dataframe adding value to a cell by matching column header and value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I have a dataframe like this :

```
Num  A    B   C   D
1    wer
1    df
1    ffg
2    asd
2    vb
3    ncnc
3    oiji
4    qwe
```

I will filter out based on `Num` first, Say I filter for `Num = 1`

```
    Num  A    B   C   D
    1    wer
    1    df
    1    ffg
```

Now I need to add value from a variable the cell where `wer` and `C` meet, similarly with `ffg` and `D`

```
Num  A    B   C   D
1    wer      5
1    df
1    ffg          7
```

If there is some value already existing, new value should replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or a easier to read, cleaner way to do it:

```
df2=df[df['Num']==1]
df2.loc[df2['A']=='wer','C']=5
df2.loc[df2['A']=='ffg','D']=7
```

Or to skip the warning, do by index:

```
df2=df[df['Num']==1]
df2.loc[0,'C']=5
df2.loc[2,'D']=7
```

Both cases:

```
print(df2)
```

Is:

```
   Num    A   B    C    D
0    1  wer NaN  5.0  NaN
1    1   df NaN  NaN  NaN
2    1  ffg NaN  NaN  7.0
```

If want to put it back to actual data frame:

```
df[df['Num']==1]=df2
```

Comment: will it be modified in dataframe?

Comment: Updating a subsetted dataframe and assigning back a subset is inefficient when you only want to update a couple of values. This isn't what [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean indexing is fundamental to Pandas: read [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

For your problem, you can construct Boolean masks and combine them to update values with [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
num_mask = df['num'] == 1
df.loc[num_mask & df['A'].eq('wer'), 'C'] = 5
df.loc[num_mask & df['A'].eq('ffg'), 'D'] = 7
```

Since the most expensive part is usually constructing the Boolean series, reusing them where possible is good practice.